# Select n items of a ContentType in OrchardCore randomly using lucene

Tags: lucene, orchardcms, querydsl

I need to select n items of a ContentType in OrchardCore randomly using query DSL but every time it returns the same result. Actually I think that it is not a correct approach. Here is the query DSL code:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": { "Content.ContentItem.ContentType": "Product" }
  },
  "sort": [
    { "Content.ContentItem.CreatedUtc": { "order": "random" } }
  ],
  "size": 3
}
```

Actually I followed this link https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/6916#issuecomment-674504976

Comment: Maybe I am not reading the [pull request](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/pull/6918) correctly (or reading the wrong PR) - but this is for a feature which has not been implemented yet. There has been no activity since December 2020.

Comment: I think they are moved to elastic search query-dsl